# Fulltext Search not searching entire string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

When searching for a specific string using CONTAINSTABLE I'm not getting back all rows that have my search criteria. It appears to be hitting a word break before getting to the end of the string. I have altered my FT index with "SET STOPLIST = OFF" and that started to return results (before I was getting nothing back), but it is still incomplete.

Here is what I'm searching for "AM and B". This will appear at the end of the string. I should get 30+ results, but I'm only getting back 4 rows. The data that is returned is in the following format "#### *word* AM B" and the data that is not returned is formatted as such "#### *word* ## AM B" (note the extra numeric characters). When I update one of the rows that is not returned and remove the two digits before "AM B" it then appears in my FT search.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a space between the numbers and `AM`?

Comment: Yes there are spaces between the numbers and AM and a space between AM and B

Comment: Can you post your SQL query and examples of the data? I'm unable to reproduce this so far. Also, did you repopulate your index after you altered it?